# Cross-validation for nonlinear models that are linear in the parameters

Tags: cross-validation, nonlinear-regression

I'd like to know if it's correct to the CV function in the **forecast** R package (http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/forecast/forecast.pdf) to cross-validate a nonlinear model that is linear in the parameters. The description in the documentation says that the CV function "Computes the leave-one-out cross-validation statistic (also known as PRESS – prediction residual sum of squares), AIC, corrected AIC, BIC and adjusted R^2 values for a **linear model**."

Thanks!

Comment: What do you mean by a "nonlinear model that is linear in the parameters"? Do you mean to say that it is nonlinear in the variables?

Comment: Yes, nonlinear in the variables, but linear in the parameters.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If a model is linear in parameters, we'd normally call it a linear model.

(It's also linear in transformed variables, the ones actually supplied to a regression function.)

So yes, it would be correct to use that CV function, since it's talking about being for the model you have.